# Return PHP MySQL select as json

Tags: php, mysql, json

So I have a SQL database with a number of objects in that contain name price and images, I would like to know how I can select them using php and output the result into json

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'car_rental') or die  ("SQL is Off");


$car = (isset($_GET['car']) ? $_GET['car'] : null);

mysqli_select_db($db,"car_rental");


$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE \'%$car%\'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

print $db_field['sku'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['name'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['img'] . "<BR>";
print $db_field['price'] . "<BR>";

}

?>
```

This is my current code car variable will change dependent on car selected 
thanks

Comment: `json_encode($db_field);`.

Comment: do i need to echo or print any of the other db_fields?

Comment: Yup.. `echo json_encode($db_field);exit;`

Comment: bro plz mention inside the loop or outside loop @Sougata

Comment: seem to get this error    mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\search.php on line 13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For getting all values in json format, you need to use like that:

```
<?
$newArr = array();
while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $newArr[] = $db_field;
}
echo json_encode($newArr); // get all products in json format.
?>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

You are mixing `mysqli` extension with `mysql`. Change `mysql` into `mysqli`

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Why are you connecting database twice in code?

**Modified Code:**

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "car_rental");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$car = (isset($_GET['car']) ? $_GET['car'] : null);

$query = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE name LIKE '%$car%'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    $newArr = array();
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $newArr[] = $db_field;
    }
    echo json_encode($newArr); // get all products in json format.    
}

?>
```

**Side Note:**

Also on [PHP error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in development phase for saving your time.

Comment: get the following error Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\search.php on line 13
false

Comment: @AhmedBakir: i have changed the variable , try now.

Comment: You are mixing mysqli extension with mysql @AhmedBakir

Comment: @AhmedBakir: Change `mysql` into `mysqli`

Comment: how should it be structured @devpro?

Comment: @AhmedBakir: just replace mysql_ with mysqli_ simple.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php   check Example #2 Procedural style @AhmedBakir

Comment: resolved error where query expects 2 parameters however i still get this errro mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\search.php on line 14
[] @devpro

Comment: thanks it works i wasnt aware that i connected to my DB twice @devpro

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't figure out what the problem is. Same style, the same commands but I get nothing encoded. Any suggestions to check?